# I made an IK foot bone and it moves the entire body while bending the foot. Anyone have any idea's why this is happening?

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

Here's the file if anyone needs it so they can help figure out the problem, thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the *Chain Length* to 2, so that only this bone and the thigh move, otherwise the IK also makes the *Lower_Body* bone move, and therefore the whole armature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, but now it's leaving a bit of the foot of the mesh behind. The heel.